# Is this a bug with the python OR operator?

Tags: python, operators

When I run the following code:

```
i = None
O = ['n', 'y', 'No', 'Yes']
while i not in O:
    i = input('Yes or No?\n')
    if i == 'y' or 'Yes':
        print('Yes')
    if i == 'n' or 'No':
        print('No')
```

The output is 
n
Yes
No

Should the code only be displaying No as the output since the first if statement was false? Or am I not understanding something?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: what does `'y' or 'Yes'` mean?

Comment: You are using it wrongly. `i == 'y' or 'Yes'` is `(i == 'y') or 'Yes'` and a non.empty string is considered true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem, you can't do:

```py
if i == 'y' or 'Yes':
```

as it is testing if `i == 'y'` or just plain `yes`. Since non-empty strings always return true, the first if statement will always run. Then the same goes for the second if statement.

So try changing:

`if i == 'y' or 'Yes':` and `if i == 'n' or 'No':`

to

`if i == 'y' or i == 'Yes':` and `if i == 'n' or i == 'No':`

like so:

```py
i = None
O = ['n', 'y', 'No', 'Yes']
while i not in O:
    i = input('Yes or No?\n')
    if i == 'y' or i == 'Yes':
        print('Yes')
    if i == 'n' or i == 'No':
        print('No')
```

> Here is an example: [click](https://repl.it/@ChezCoder/StackOverflow)

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly state `i ==` in your second check; `if i =='y' or i == 'Yes'`

What you have done is

```
i == 'n' or 'No'
'No'
```

`i` is equal to `n` or `No` < This outputs `No` as is it not equal to `n`

```
i == 'n' or i == 'No'
False
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this in your code:

```
if i == 'y' or 'Yes':
```

The meaning of this in Python (and in most programming languages) is:

```
if (i == 'y') or ('Yes'):
```

Clearly not what you intended. Since `'Yes'` evaluates to true, and anything OR true is true, your `if`s body will execute.

To get what you want, you should write:

```
if i == 'y' or i == 'Yes':
```

Same for the "no" branch.